# How to disable ctrl+click to select text in IE 10?

Tags: click, textselection, internet-explorer-10, ctrl

In IE 10, when you click on any text while holding the <kbd>CTRL</kbd> key the browser selects the text (which means the text gains focus and I want to avoid this because I have some multi-select scenario where <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+click means add/remove-select).

How can I disable this "feature"?

BTW, I still want to be able to select the text using the usual mouse actions.

Comment: You need to talk to some UI boys. Overriding standard behaviours is something users find confusing and irritating, leaving them with the impression that you couldn't be bothered with them.

Comment: I think you comment should be forwarded to the IE10 team... ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This feature can be disabled by disabling selection completely.

This can be done by using **-ms-user-select** which has been introduced in IE10.
(see also: http://ie.microsoft.com/testdrive/HTML5/msUserSelect/Default.html)

**Example:** To disable selection add the following css class to the element containing the text or one of its parents:

```
.notselectable
{
    -ms-user-select: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent IE 8 <kbd>CTRL</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> click text selection on individual element, use this:

```
var obj = document.createElement("DIV");
obj.onselectstart = function(){
  return false;
}
```

To prevent text selection on document, use this:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.onselectstart = function(){
    return false;
  }
}
```